# How `DispatcherServlet` inherits methods from `GenericServlet`

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was learning Spring MVC, wherein I came across `DispatcherServlet`. The API [doc says](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) `DispatcherServlet` inherits methods `getInitParameter, getInitParameterNames, getServletConfig, getServletContext` from `GenericServlet` class.

However, on the same page, it says

```
public class DispatcherServlet extends FrameworkServlet
```

It does not say it extends `GenericServlet` class (neither [`FrameworkServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html) extends `GenericServlet`). Also in the [github source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2255d222e311ade8813308626ea2da954c7825c0/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L162), I dont find how `DispatcherServlet` inherits methods `getInitParameter()`, `getServletContext()` from `GenericServlet`.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Javadocs always show the class hierarchy under the class name. For the first link you gave, they show `java.lang.Object>avax.servlet.GenericServlet>javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet>org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`

Comment: As you can see in the link you specified,  frameworkservlet has genericservlet in its hierarchy

Comment: ohhh yeah I just noticed...was fiddling for long to determine how we can access init params, servlet context params etc. So was lost and fed up understanding the whole Spring framework API class hierarchy. My bad, I didnt noticed]

Comment: @ernest_k Is the detailed class diagram / design document of the Spring framework available online?